# are you sure button sql databse

Tags: javascript, button

I want to make an **"Are you sure?"** button before any changes to my database are made.

The form and code that I use are the following, can anyone help me with this cause I can't figure it out

```
<form method="post" action="php_code.php" >
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
        <label>Inkoopprijs</label>
        <label>
            <input type="number" step="any" name="inkoopprijs" value="">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Verkoopprijs</label>
        <label>
            <input type="number" step="any" name="verkoopprijs" value="">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div id="product" class="input-group">
        <label>product</label>
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="producten" value="">
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
        <?php if ($update == true):?>
            <button onclick="update_time" class="btn" type="submit" name="update" style="background: darkorange;" >Update</button>
        <?php else: ?>
            <button class="btn" type="submit" name="save" >Save</button>
        <?php endif ?>
        <a class="btn" href="index.php">Home</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $inkoopprijs = $_POST['inkoopprijs'];
    $verkoopprijs = $_POST['verkoopprijs'];
    $last_modified = $_POST['last_modified'];

    mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE prijzen SET inkoopprijs='$inkoopprijs', verkoopprijs='$verkoopprijs', last_modified= '$last_modified' WHERE id=$id");
    $_SESSION['message'] = "price updated!";
    header('location: C_R_U_D.php');
```

`

i have tried alerts, and even after i hit cancel it still did the editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `onclick` event handler to your `Save` or `Update` button. Once the button is clicked, call built-in [`confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) function that returns `true` or `false` depending on user's choice. In case of `false`, you would like to prevent browser's default behavior and cancel form submission, which may be achieved by calling `event.preventDefault()`.

```js
<button type="submit" onclick="confirm('Are you sure?') || event.preventDefault()">Save</button>
```

Comment: thanks @Vadim, im just a beginner with coding and never heard of that event. i worked!